# How to run Meteor.js locally but connecting mongo to mongodb.com in Windows

Tags: windows, mongodb, meteor

I have a Meteor app deployed on AWS using database from mongodb.com, and it's working fine.
now I want to be able to work with the same database instead of local when I run my app locally for development (along with my settings.json). I tried everything but the problem is all solutions work on none Windows machines.
here is the latest command I tried but nothing happens:

```
set MONGO_URL=mongodb://<username>:<password>@<mydatabase>.mongodb.net:27017/meteor meteor --settings settings.json
```

what's the solution?

Comment: How is "working fine" defined here? How do you connect to it? Is it running on 27017 and via public ip available? Is the database working? What do you mean by "nothing happens"?

Comment: **working fine:** when deploy, I set the env like the following: 
`MONGO_URL: 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@vhdatabase-tngvp.mongodb.net/meteor?authSource=admin&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&replicaSet=VHDataBase-shard-0&ssl=true'`
and data base connection and everything is working.
**nothing happens:** when i hit enter in command line, goes to the next line like i did nothing at all

Comment: Im not sure how it works in windows but on mac I do it like this

export MONGO_URL=YOUR_URL && meteor run --settings=settings.json

Try adding the && after your mongo_url, and also try enclosing the MONGO_URL in quote marks ""

Comment: Did you try: `MONGO_URL="<DB_username>:<_DB_password>@<DB_host>:<DB_Port>/<DB_Name>" meteor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue as well, the solution that worked for me was to create a BAT file within the root project folder containing the full run command for Meteor.

1. In the root directory create a bat file such as `run.bat`
2. Edit the BAT file to contain your Meteor start command:

```
SET MONGO_URL=mongodb+srv://username:password@production.mongodb.net/root meteor run --settings settings.json
```

3. Run the file.

Comment: Had to put `meteor --settings settings.json` on the second line. but it worked! after 3 weeks of trying. thank you.
`SET MONGO_URL=mongodb+srv://username:password@production.mongodb.net/meteor?authSource=admin
meteor --settings settings.json`